# How to use conditional placeholder in custom template [wp plugin]

Tags: wordpress

I am using [event manger](http://wp-events-plugin.com) plugin.

How to use this code in a custom template file??

```
{fully_booked}content{/fully_booked}
```

Comment: Could you be more specific in your problem? what are you attempting to do??

Comment: i want to check the events ticket is fully booked.if fully booked i have to show some divs

Answer (score 1):

You have to put your `HTML content` between the **conditional placeholder**. For example:

```
{fully_booked}
<div id="myId">
   <p>
      There are not tickets available
   </p>
</div>
{/fully_booked}
```

Content will only be displayed if the condition is met, otherwise the whole placeholder will be omitted.

More info in [Events Manager Doc](http://wp-events-plugin.com/documentation/conditional-placeholders/)

**[UPDATED]**

You can use it fomr PHP too, but it is a bit different. In the Plugin page you have a [tutorial](http://wp-events-plugin.com/tutorials/creating-conditional-placeholders-for-events/)

Comment: but i cant use this place holder simply in php.

Comment: the above mebtioned placed holder is already thre. idont want to create new one